# Como acessar uma variável de outra função?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Fala galera, encontrei uma dificuldade, iniciante em JS.

Tenho 2 funções:

```
function getHeight() {
var tdHeight = document.querySelector(".info-altura").textContent;
console.log(tdHeight);
}


function getWeight() {
var tdWeight = document.querySelector(".info-peso").textContent;
console.log(tdWeight);;
}
```

Agora criei uma q vai pegar o resultado da função getWeight e getHeight para poder fazer um calculo, porém me retorna undefined.

```
function calcImc() {
var resultImc = tdWeight / (tdHeight * tdHeight);
console.log(resultImc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em javascript temos os escopos de variáveis, devemos ter em mente que devemos:

1) restringir ao máximo a utilização desse escopo, mas o que é esse escopo?

O escopo global é onde se pode ter variáveis **soltas** dentro do arquivo como por exemplo:

```
let minhaVariavel = 'variavel global'
```

lembre sempre de declarar suas variáveis com o let pois essa é a forma mais nova que a linguagem implementou para algumas melhorias de problemas.

temos também o escopo de função, que temos as variáveis dentro de uma função e a mesma só será enxergada dentro da mesma, essa seria a forma mais correta de trabalhar mas não a única, ex:

```
function minhaFuncao() { 
   let minhaVar = 'variável de função é local' 
   return minhaVar
}
```

para resolver o problema que na realidade é uma solução podemos retornar em cada função o valor e depois somar tudo.

```js
const tdHeight = function() {
    return "alguma coisa"
}

const tdWeight = function() {
    return "mais outra coisa"
}
const result = function(){
    return tdHeight() + tdWeight()
}

console.log(result())
```

outra saída seria atribuir a variáveis globais

```js
let tdHeight
let tdWeight

function getHeight() {
 tdHeight = "alguma coisa"
}

function getDWeight() {
    tdWeight = "mais outra coisa"
}
const result = function(){
    return tdHeight + tdWeight
}
getHeight()
getDWeight()
console.log(result())
```

Comment: obrigado pela explicação detalhada!

Answer (score 3):

Olá ! 
No codigo acima, você faz um console.log com os valores que pegou.
Tente fazer um return dos valores no lugar do console.log.

A variável criada no contexto da função, existe apenas no contexto da função. 
O que você pode fazer é fazer a substituição do 'console.log' por 'return' e em vez de chamar as variáveis criadas nas funções, chame a função em si, que ela retornará o valor.

Comment: Oi Giovane, tudo bem?
Tentei adicionar um "return tdHeight" e mesmo assim não consigo acessar

Comment: funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Também poderia fazer desta forma: criar uma função "pai" que contenha as duas funções referente a peso e altura, com isso, não deixaria suas variáveis em escopo global!

```js
function imc() {

    function altura (){
        let dadoAltura = parseFloat(prompt('Digite sua altura: '))
        return dadoAltura;
    }

    function peso () {
        let dadoPeso = parseFloat(prompt('Digite seu peso: '))
        return dadoPeso
    }

    return peso() / (altura()**2)
}

console.log(imc())
```